# Wordpress - list all pages in a hierarchy

Tags: wordpress, navigation

How does one list all the pages in WP, so that they form a hierarchy?

```
Home
    Sub page
    Other page
About Us
    About us subpage
    Lorem ipsum
        Sub sub page
```

I need this for main site navigation. The output could be done via `ul` tags for example.
I tried `wp_list_pages()` - but that only lists the first level of navigation.

Is there any particular template tag in Wordpress for something like this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [WordPress Stack Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the steps:

1. Create a new menu in `Dashboard` > `Appearance` > `Menus`.
2. Add pages in to the menu maintaining the heirarchy(ie. child page should be added below the parent page).
3. Use the function `wp_nav_menu()` to display the menu.

Inorder to know more about WordPress menu creation please look at this link: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide and for `wp_nav_menu()` function please go through the link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu.

Answer (score 1):

Create a menu in the admin side and then use this function [`wp_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a Text Widget and insert each page link with in-line CSS or use as mentioned the ul and li tags.